# In magento 2, Edit the image uploaded image field works in localhost but not works in server

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, image-upload

In magento 2, Edit the image uploaded image field works in localhost but not works in server

I follow this blog https://blog.qaisarsatti.com/magento_2/magento-2-ui-component-image-upload/

> Before Save

[image]

> After saved a form image  saved in db

[image]

> After saved and edit form

[image]

> app/code/Cm/Module/view/adminhtml/ui-component/sales_rule_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
  <dataSource name="sales_rule_form_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Cm\Module\Model\SalesRule\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">sales_rule_form_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">rule_id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="sales_rule/promo_quote/save"/>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="highlight_promotion">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Highlight Promotion</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <field name="promo_image">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">helloworld</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Image</item>
                    <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">fileUploader</item>
                    <item name="elementTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/form/element/uploader/uploader</item>
                    <item name="previewTmpl" xsi:type="string">Cm_Module/image-preview</item>
                    <item name="required" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="uploaderConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="cm_module/index/upload"/>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
   </field>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

> app/code/Cm/Module/Model/SalesRule/DataProvider.php

```
<?php
namespace Cm\Module\Model\SalesRule;
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\Collection;
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\ResourceModel\Rule\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule;

/**
 * Class DataProvider
 */
class DataProvider extends \Magento\Ui\DataProvider\AbstractDataProvider
{
    /**
     * @var Collection
     */
    protected $collection;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $loadedData;

    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $coreRegistry;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Metadata\ValueProvider
     */
    protected $metadataValueProvider;

    /**
     * Initialize dependencies.
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @param string $primaryFieldName
     * @param string $requestFieldName
     * @param CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param Metadata\ValueProvider $metadataValueProvider
     * @param array $meta
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        $name,
        $primaryFieldName,
        $requestFieldName,
        CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Metadata\ValueProvider $metadataValueProvider,
        array $meta = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->collection = $collectionFactory->create();
        $this->coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->_storeManager=$storeManager;
        $this->metadataValueProvider = $metadataValueProvider;
        $meta = array_replace_recursive($this->getMetadataValues(), $meta);
        parent::__construct($name, $primaryFieldName, $requestFieldName, $meta, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get metadata values
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getMetadataValues()
    {
        $rule = $this->coreRegistry->registry(\Magento\SalesRule\Model\RegistryConstants::CURRENT_SALES_RULE);
        return $this->metadataValueProvider->getMetadataValues($rule);
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getData()
    {

        if(isset($this->loadedData))
        {
            return $this->loadedData;
        }
        $items = $this->collection->getItems();
        $baseurl =  $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBasUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
        /** @var Rule $rule */
        foreach ($items as $rule) {

            $this->loadedData[$rule->getId()] = $rule->getData();
             if($rule->getPromoImage()) {
                $m['promo_image'][0]['name'] = $rule->getPromoImage();
                $m['promo_image'][0]['url'] = $this->getMediaUrl().$rule->getPromoImage();
               $fullData = $this->loadedData;
                $this->loadedData[$rule->getId()] = array_merge($fullData[$rule->getId()], isset($m));
            }
        } 
        return $this->loadedData;
    }
    public function getMediaUrl()
    {
        $mediaUrl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()
            ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'test/tmp/';
        return $mediaUrl;
    }
}
```

> app/code/Cm/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<virtualType name="Cm\Module\ImageUpload" type="Cm\Module\Model\ImageUploader">
    <arguments>
            <argument name="baseTmpPath" xsi:type="string">test/tmp</argument>
            <argument name="basePath" xsi:type="string">test</argument>
            <argument name="allowedExtensions" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="jpg" xsi:type="string">jpg</item>
                <item name="jpeg" xsi:type="string">jpeg</item>
                <item name="gif" xsi:type="string">gif</item>
                <item name="png" xsi:type="string">png</item>
            </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
<type name="Cm\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Upload">
    <arguments>
            <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">Cm\Module\ImageUpload</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<type name="Cm\ModuleModel\SalesRule\DataProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">Cm\Module\ImageUpload</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<type name="Cm\Module\Observer\SaveImage">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="imageUploader" xsi:type="object">Cm\Module\ImageUpload</argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement">
        <plugin name="ken_save_custom_fee_in_quote" type="Cm\Module\Plugin\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Someone please help me resolve this issue

Comment: I think you missed some files to upload...Can you please update `di.xml`...Which is used to override dataprovider?

Comment: Where this file called from `Cm\Module\Model\SalesRule\DataProvider`?

Comment: DataProvider file  calls in the sales_rule_form.xml file

Comment: In DataProvider remove isset($m), and add only $m.

Comment: i will check that way its not working

Comment: Yes,...I just convey, got error when i try your code

Comment: its working in localhost but not working in the server

Comment: Any error in log in you server?

Comment: no error reflect  log file

Comment: when open a edit form  its show a f Uncaught TypeError: value.map is not a function  error in console

Comment: Make print_r($this->loadedData); in getData function and post screenshot pls.

Comment: i was  give print_r($this->loadedData);  but when i open a  form to edit  there is no value is printed https://prnt.sc/phv6k0

Comment: Did that print_r worked in local?

Comment: in local its works

Comment: Please check `sales_rule_form.xml` in server file with local file

Comment: i replace local sales_rule_form.xml file into server. its not works

Comment: I think....some third party modules makes this issue...The problem is your dataprovider is not taken in sales_rule_form....Check with other modules, Is there any sales_rule_form.xml file exists

Comment: i  also checked in the developer mode there is no error  arrive for this image upload

Comment: Ok for testing purpose...Can you please put that print_r in `vendor/magento/module-sales-rule/Model/Rule/DataProvider.php`

Comment: i already testing like that  way that works in core file

Comment: Then override this file using plugin...To avoid such issue...Do i need to post demo?

Comment: how to override DataProvider.php via  plugin

Comment: Will update the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> app/code/Cm/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\DataProvider">
    <plugin name="data_provider_custom" type="Cm\Module\Plugin\Dataprovider" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
</type>
```

> app\code\Cm\Module\Plugin\Dataprovider.php

```
<?php
namespace Cm\Module\Plugin\Rule;
/**
 * Class DataProvider
 */
class DataProvider
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    protected $storeManager;
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
    ) {
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
    }
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function afterGetData(
        \Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\DataProvider $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
            $result[$key]['promo_image'] = array(
                array('name' => $value['promo_image'],
                'url' => $this->getMediaUrl().$result[$key]['promo_image'])
            );
        }
        return $result;
    }
    /**
     * @return string media url
     */
    public function getMediaUrl()
    {
        $mediaUrl = $this->_storeManager->getStore()
            ->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'test/tmp/';
        return $mediaUrl;
    }
}
```

Please adjust your plugin logic...May be it has some error...

Comment: thanks for your  code  i will check and update you

Comment: i was used a plugin  but  its not works

Comment: Did you removed datasource code in `sales_rule_form.xml`?

Comment: i removed it from sales_rule_from.xml

Comment: i still get the file-uploader.js:69 Uncaught TypeError: value.map is not a function  error in console

Comment: If you try to create new rule, then the error still exists?

Comment: S i m still getting that issue after i create a new rule

Comment: I will try in my env...and let you know

Comment: i  upload a code in github and share you

Comment: sounds good....ok

Comment: can you please  accept the github invitation https://github.com/sd2894/app-code-Bootsgrid-specialPromotion/invitations

Comment: I have committed `Dataprovider.php` plugin file . Please check

Comment: ok i will check and update you

Comment: Thank you so much   finally  its works  thanks for your effective help sir

Comment: Welcome mam....